# Earliest Substitution after kickoff in an official football match

Tags: football, trivia

Which team holds the record for the earliest substitution after kick-off in an official football match?

I personally have seen games where players have gotten substituted within the first twenty minutes. But how early does the record stand?

It would also be great if you could include the earliest non-injury substitution too. (I do agree this one might be tougher to come by)

Comment: The author doesn't seem certain of whether or not it is the earliest non-injury substitution, but ["Vitesse took off their left-back Haim Megrelishvili after only six minutes](http://www.theguardian.com/football/2008/apr/09/theknowledge.sport) due to his poor defending, as the manager later explained," Rutger Ijzermans told us last week. "Is this the quickest ever substitution that was not due to injury?"

Comment: The Guardian article [The earliest ever tactical substitutions](http://www.theguardian.com/football/2008/apr/09/theknowledge.sport) mentions a few quick substitutions. (I simply googled for [earliest substitution](http://www.google.com/search?q=earliest+substition) and [quickest substitution](http://www.google.com/search?q=quickest+substition), this page come first in both searches. Other hits might contain some interesting information, too.) It is the same article which was mentioned in Nocholas V.'s comment.

Comment: I quote from that article: *After just two minutes of play, Beck replaced the club captain Grant Brown with the midfielder Steve Brown.* This is about a match between Lincoln City and Swansea City. A match from Norwegian first division where a player was substituted after one minute is also mentioned there.

Answer (score 7):

A recent Italian football game between Nocerina and Salernitana saw three subs in the first two minutes.

However, these were due to the team wanting the match abandoned after receiving death threats. Two more players left the pitch due to injury in the first 17 minutes and two more were sent off, forcing the referee to call the game off.

Source: http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/24899997

Comment: Just as an addition to the above, as a result Nocerina were thrown out of the league.